# update database with time value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a drop down to enter time with AM and PM values like this-12.00 Am,12.30 AM ..and I want to enter this time to my data base and my field is in Time format.how can I enter that values into database?

```
<input type="text" id="picktime" name="dueTime" class="time" value="{$taskData->dueTime}" style="width:88%"/>
    <script>
                              $(function() {
                                $('#picktime').timepicker();
                              });
                              </script>
```

In sql "Update tasks set dueTime = $_POST['dueTime']"

Comment: The way you add the data to your database is not secure. See "sql injection". You are most likely able to validate the input and format it to wanted timeformat by giving php the full time (year,month,day,hour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$format="%H:%M:%S";
UPDATE tasks SET dueTime = '".strftime($format,strtottime($_POST['dueTime']))."'
```

This will get you "00:00:00" for "12:00 Am", "00:30:00" for "12:30 AM", etc.  Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php and modify **$format** accordingly to suit your needs.